# Autofilling values in AngularJS in new document from table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

So I'm working on a project where there's a table of different instances of our service and each row has a info button that pulls up a form with info from the row autofilled into it.

**The problem:**
By the time I get the value for the row, the page is already rendered so I can't seem to autofill the information.

**What I want:**
When the form is shown, the input fields will be filled from the value inside the table for that row.

the code is shortened and I just wanted to post what was necessary.

**Code:**

**InfoForm.html**

```
<form  name="info_change_request_form">
  <div >
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input maxlength="255" type="text" name="name" ng-model="info_request.name" required="true"/>
    </md-input-container class="md-block">
  </div>

  <div>
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input maxlength="255" type="email" name="email" ng-model="info_request.email" required="true"/>
    </md-input-container class="md-block">
  </div>

  <div>
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label>Summary</label>
      <input maxlength="255" type="text" name="summary" ng-model="info_request.summary" rows="5" required="true"/>
    </md-input-container class="md-block">
  </div>
```

**Table.html**

```
<tbody md-body>
          <tr md-row ng-repeat="info in infos">
            <td md-cell>{{info.name}}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{info.email}}</td>
            <td md-cell>
              <md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target" flex="50">
```

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.newInfoForm = function(info) {
  // Build the confirm dialog
  var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm({
    controller: 'InfoController',
    templateUrl: 'app/informationtables/info_change.html',
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    parent: angular.element(document.body)
  });
  // Show confirm dialog and updates projects list
  // Creation is called upon submitting the form (see create(project))
  $mdDialog.show(confirm).finally(function() {
    // TODO: callback?
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to display the dialog after getting data from server:

```
$http.get(api_url).then(function(data) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        locals:{dataToPass: data.infos},                           
        templateUrl: 'your_template_url',
        controller: InfoController,
    });
}
```

and in the InfoController:

```
function InfoController ($scope, dataToPass) { 
    $scope.infos = dataToPass  
}
```

Comment: at this point, though, the data is already received and on the table from the api request, so I am trying to just handle it with the data that was already received

Comment: You can use the observer pattern. create a callback function that update the variables tied to the view. When you receive the row data, you call this callback.

Comment: Any examples? I understand the observer pattern but can't think of how to implement for angularjs

Comment: Everytime you get the row data for the table, you have to notify the dialog the new data. right?
You can do this in two ways:
1) Using Events: when you get the table data, you send an event passing the row data. In the dialog controller you get that event and put the data in the scope.
2) Using Observer Pattern: create a callback inside the dialog controller. Create a service and inside you store callback and the methods "notify" and "register". Inside the dialog controller you call register (callback). When you get the table data you call the notify function.